# How to find an infinite recursion error in a Java program?

Tags: java, recursion, infinite

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.*;


    public class TMS {

        private static int row = 5, col = 5;
        private static String[][] board = new String[row][col];
        private static String[][] board_copy = new String[row][col];

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for(String[] array:board) {
                Arrays.fill(array, "_");
            }
            create_mines();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int inpx = 0, inpy;

            while(inpx != 69){
                show_board();
                inpx = input.nextInt();
                inpy = input.nextInt();
                if(board_copy[inpx][inpy] == "*"){
                    System.out.println("YOU LOOSE");
                    break;
                }
                check_move(inpx, inpy);
            }
        }

        public static void show_board() {
            for(String[] row: board){
                for(String element: row){
                    System.out.print(element+"\t");
                }System.out.println();
            }
        }

        public static void create_mines() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            rand.nextInt();

            for(String[] array:board_copy) {
                Arrays.fill(array, "_");
            }
            board_copy[1][1] = "*";
            board_copy[3][1] = "*";
            board_copy[3][3] = "*";
            board_copy[2][4] = "*";
        }

        public static void check_move(int posx, int posy){
            int mines = 0;
            if(posx-1 >= 0 && posy-1 >= 0)
                mines = (board_copy[posx-1][posy-1] == "*")? (mines+1):mines;
            if(posx >= 0 && posy-1 >= 0)
                mines = (board_copy[posx][posy-1] == "*")? (mines+1):mines;
            if(posx+1 < row && posy+1 < col)
                mines = (board_copy[posx+1][posy+1] == "*")? (mines+1):mines;
            if(posx-1 >= 0 && posy >= 0)
                mines = (board_copy[posx-1][posy] == "*")? (mines+1):mines;
            if(posx+1 < row && posy >= 0)
                mines = (board_copy[posx+1][posy] == "*")? (mines+1):mines;
            if(posx >= 0 && posy+1 < col)
                mines = (board_copy[posx][posy+1] == "*")? (mines+1):mines;
            if(posx-1 >= 0 && posy+1 < col)
                mines = (board_copy[posx-1][posy+1] == "*")? (mines+1):mines;
            if(posx+1 < row && posy-1 >= 0)
                mines = (board_copy[posx+1][posy-1] == "*")? (mines+1):mines;
            board[posx][posy] = Integer.toString(mines);

            if(mines == 0){
                if((posx-1) >= 0 && (posy-1) >= 0) {
                    System.out.println((posx-1)+" "+(posy-1));
                    check_move((posx - 1), (posy - 1));
                }
                if(posx >= 0 && (posy-1) >= 0) {
                    System.out.println((posx)+" "+(posy-1));
                    check_move(posx, (posy - 1));
                }
                if((posx+1) < row && (posy+1) < col) {
                    System.out.println((posx+1)+" "+(posy+1));
                    check_move((posx + 1), (posy + 1));
                }
                if((posx-1) >= 0 && posy >= 0) {
                    System.out.println((posx-1)+" "+(posy));
                    check_move((posx - 1), posy);
                }
                if((posx+1) < row && posy >= 0) {
                    System.out.println((posx+1)+" "+(posy));
                    check_move((posx + 1), posy);
                }
                if(posx >= 0 && (posy+1) < col) {
                    System.out.println((posx)+" "+(posy+1));
                    check_move(posx, (posy + 1));
                }
                if((posx-1) >= 0 && (posy+1) < col) {
                    System.out.println((posx-1)+" "+(posy+1));
                    check_move((posx - 1), (posy + 1));
                }
                if((posx+1) < row && (posy-1) >= 0) {
                    System.out.println((posx+1)+" "+(posy-1));
                    check_move((posx + 1), (posy - 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Apparently, I'm calling the method check_move infinitely during recursion. I can't find out why is it going on infinitely. Here's the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:402)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:70)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:79)
    at TMS.check_move(TMS.java:95)
    .
    .
    .
    .
(GOES ON FOREVER)
```

Comment: You must have gotten a stackoverflow exception. If you post the stack trace that leads to stackoverflow that will help find the cause.

Comment: I'm new to java so i have no idea

Comment: If you don't have enough diagnostic skill to debug through this code, I would suggest starting with something simpler - basically, don't try to write something that you don't know how to debug into. Take small steps to start with.

Comment: Your check_moves function is recursive but does not contain a clear "base case" which will terminate the recursion. That's likely why it never stops. Also recursive methods generally return a value to the caller.

Comment: Unrelated, but how can `inpx` *ever* be `69`?

Comment: @Andreas, how about as a result of the line inpx = input.nextInt(); ?

Comment: @Penguino Followed by `board_copy[inpx][inpy]`, so a value of `69` would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and the `while(inpx != 69)` condition can never be `false`.

Comment: @Andreas Yep, that is the case, I didn't consider that. But inpx will still be 69 when the exception is raised (so I am technically correct :)).

Comment: @Penguino Not where it is tested against `69`, and that's what my question was about. But sure, it'll temporarily be `69`, and I should have been more clear: *Unrelated, but how can `inpx` ever be `69` **in `while(inpx != 69)`**?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursion won't end if, for example, you have two adjacent cells without mines. For example, if at some position (posx,posy) there is no mine you call check_move at (posx-1,posy-1) in the line

```
  if((posx-1) >= 0 && (posy-1) >= 0) {
      System.out.println((posx-1)+" "+(posy-1));
      check_move((posx - 1), (posy - 1));
```

Now, if (posx-1,posy-1) also has no mines, you will call check_move at (posx,posy) in the line

```
if((posx+1) < row && (posy+1) < col) {
    System.out.println((posx+1)+" "+(posy+1));
    check_move((posx + 1), (posy + 1));
```

And this will continue forever. You need to find a means to end recursion in all cases. For example, you could have a 'checked' flag on each cell that stops you from re-calling check_move in an already tested position (there may be other ways...).

And as Andreas points out, your inpx = 69 won't have the desired effect, as your routine will call an exception before it gets back to the while loop test.